# Applying CSS properties via id attribute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to re-create the SHARKFIN:

> [image: Screenshot]

HTML and CSS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>SHARKFIN</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <style>
            .logo {font:70px Montserrat; color:white}
            .fin {color:#43C4DD !important ;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="logo">SH<span id="a">A</span>RK<span id="fin">FIN</span></div> <!--SHARKFIN broken into parts-->
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: -1 for non-specific title.

Comment: use `#` before logo in  css for cheer up. ID identifier is `#` symbol not `.`.

Comment: Also, no need for `!important`. Just make sure the second color is given after the first color.

Answer (score 3):

The *id* attribute is selected with `#` and the *class* attribute is selected with  `.`

Change your HTML:

1. `id="logo"`  to  `class="logo"`
2. `id="fin"` to `class="fin"`

***Or*** instead  you can:

Change your CSS:

1. `.logo`  to `#logo`
2. `.fin` to `#fin`

Comment: derp...thanks man. so simple